# Связка php + mdb

Tags: unix, php, mysql

```
echo "Добрый день.";
```

И вопрос у нас сегодня таков: как сделать чтение и запись в `*.mdb` файлик на хостинге, не имеющем баз **с помощью php**. Хостинг unix.

Comment: А смысл этого гемороя? Поставьте mariadb и не парьтесь. Или у вас нет ssh доступа к серверу?

Comment: Смысл в том, что есть бесплатный хостинг, на котором нету мускула, а надо сделать cms мелкую, но с какой никакой базой - первое что приходит на ум - mdb. В нете пишут, но муть какую-то и под винду.

Comment: Лучше SQLite возьмите. Плоские файлы, работает везде, и более-менее полноценный sql.

Comment: никакой проблемы нет! Главное чтобы на хостинге поддержка ODBC была

Comment: Да вы батенька извращенец! Наверное я даже еще таких не видел ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я уже сказал, главное чтобы на хостинге была поддержка ODBC, ну а дальше стандартные процедуры: коннект к базе (в данном случае mdb-файлу), запрос на выборку, вывод результата.

```
$connect = odbc_connect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $password);
$query = "SELECT * FROM customers";
$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query!");
odbc_close($connect);
```

Comment: Простите, но автор ЯВНО сказал что там unix машина. где вы на юниксе видели Microsoft Access Driver??? Прошу прощения, действительно есть ODBC под unix

Answer (score 0):

[Работа с MS Access в PHP](http://citforum.ru/internet/php/access_php/). А еще есть такое, как SQLite. Но хост может не поддерживать!